# GWT widget for "reading pane" seen in Google Reader?

Tags: gwt, widget, gxt

Is there a way to easily simulate Google Reader's reading pane functionality using combination of standard GWT widgets and panels?

I need a table, or a list of "headers" for my data. This list should be scrollable and/or paginated, but individual items should be "expandable" for reading in detail. Expanded items should simply extend the scrollable area of the entire list (i.e. use the same scrollbar and do not introduce a second one).

From what I can see, none of the existing panels and widgets can achieve this. Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CellList` with a complex `Cell` that reacts to click events to expand/collapse.

As for the inifinite scrolling, there's an example in the Showcase sample: http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList